# Horizontal Lines in Android App Background

Tags: android, user-interface

If you look at the attached image (Google+), or you have this app on your android device, you'll see on the main menu that the background has these horizontal lines that fill it. How exactly do you do this?

Is it a simple image, or a horizontal line that is somehow repeated to fill the screen and give the same effect?

[image]

Comment: they are not horizontal, are they?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes it's not horizontal it's... diagonal... My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same using similar **background image** for the layout

Comment: So it is definitely an image that is being used, NOT some other fancy 'object repeat' manoeuvre?